# SQL Server : Error_Line returns line number which does not match with stored procedure line number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which is about 4000 lines long; I get a error in line number 699, but I know SSMS takes line number differently. Is there any way to find the exact line number?

Approach I have tried so far.

1. Copy pasted the stored procedure to an editing tool and checked the line number
2. Tried debugging but was not able to
3. Tried this `sp_helptext proc_name`, but this query doesn't execute

Is there any way to find out the correct line number ?

Comment: In SSMS you can go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Transact SQL -> Display -> Ckeck the 'Line Numbers' textbox and hit OK.

Comment: are you using dynamic sql by any chance? then SSMS may not be able to pin point the line number correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check definition in sys.sql_modules:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('proc_name');
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=574e840f9f700cf60039c1684ad2565b)**

---

**EDIT:**

And with split to specific row:

```
SELECT s.object_id, s.definition, s2.*
FROM sys.sql_modules s
CROSS APPLY (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1/0) 
             FROM STRING_SPLIT(s.definition, CHAR(10))) s2(line, rn)
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('test')  -- proc name
  AND rn = 5;  -- error line
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2202df1eb9397060ba5d38630e3ee8f3)**

**[DBFiddle Demo3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6ea0bb07c062892ea14f50788df19232)**

Comment: invalid object name string_split

Comment: @PrabhatGaur  [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) -> *SQL Server 2016 and later*